Capture of variable with non-sendable type NSImage in a '@Sendable closure'
I'm new to swift concurrency, I noticed that my code freezes UI when trying to initialize NSImage, so I decided to do it on the global thread like this:
func chooseImage() {
    Task { @MainActor in
        
        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.prompt = "Select File"
        openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
        openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
        openPanel.allowedContentTypes = [.image]
        openPanel.begin { (result) -> Void in
            if result.rawValue == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK.rawValue {
                guard let url = openPanel.url else {return}
                self.fileURL = url
                loading = true
                DispatchQueue.global(qos:.userInitiated).async
                {
                    guard let chosenImage = NSImage(contentsOf: url) else { return }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async()
                    {
                        autoreleasepool {
                            self.nsImage = chosenImage
                        }
                        self.recongizeText()
                        loading = false
                    }
                }
   }

Does this mean that NSImage is not thread safe? does this warning really mean that there might be some kind of race condition, and if so what would be the best way to fix this?

You can always check the documentation to see what a type conforms to but yes, NSImage is not Sendable. If you are new to Swift concurrency then I suggest you focus on learning the new async/await implementation and ignore DispatchQueue and such and definitely don't mix them like you have done here.

@JoakimDanielson I'm not sure if the warning is just the compiler being too strict considering that I have run my app for a while now and haven't seen it crash, I don't know how I could implement await for initializing an NSImage

As mentioned in the comments mixing GCD and Swift Concurrency is bad practice.
This is a translation to async/await
@MainActor
func chooseImage() async  {
    
    let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    openPanel.prompt = "Select File"
    openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
    openPanel.allowedContentTypes = [.image]
    let result = await openPanel.begin()
    guard result == .OK, let url = openPanel.url else { return }
    self.fileURL = url
    loading = true
    let task = Task.detached {
        try? Data(contentsOf: url)
    }
    guard let data = await task.value, let image = NSImage(data: data) else { return }
    self.nsImage = image
    self.recongizeText() 
    loading = false
}


Wow that was easier than I expected, thanks. I will read up the documentation on Task.detached since I never saw this before, I only used GCD so far

@vadian gives the best "how?" answer. My answer is to the "why?"
NSImage is explicitly documented not to be thread-safe, except when used in specific ways, which makes it non-Sendable. It would be very nice if this documentation were in the NSImage page itself, but it is explained in the Thread Safety Summary of the Threading Programming Guide, under NSImage Restrictions (emphasis added):

One thread can create an NSImage object, draw to the image buffer, and pass it off to the main thread for drawing. The underlying image cache is shared among all threads.

NSImage was designed at a time when threading was pretty rare and almost painfully explicit, unlike today's world of concurrency everywhere. UIImage, for example, is thread safe. But various operations on NSImage that modify the cache can cause safety problems. As with mutable Foundation objects, the general rule is "any thread is ok, but only one at a time."
Technically what you're doing is fine. You construct the NSImage on a background thread, and then pass it to the main thread for use. The compiler today just cannot prove that you never use the image on two threads. When SE-0414 is available, almost certainly after WWDC, this code may become legal.
In the meantime (and if SE-0414 doesn't fix this case), I'd probably use @vadian's answer. The other approach, and the one I usually use in my own code, is to work entirely in CGImage, which is thread-safe/Sendable, and convert to NSImage/UIImage only when needed. I often do this for portability reasons between iOS and Mac as much as thread-safety. If that's not a concern for you, and you don't have more complex needs than this, then @vadian's answer is best (though I highly recommend adding some error checking instead of try?).

I wrote try? because the URL is guaranteed to be valid.

But the load is not guaranteed to succeed. For example, the file might be truncated while it is being read. (This is Mac, afterall; the user can get to the file directly.) It's conceivable that this will still not throw an error, but if it did, I sure would like to know what happened.

@RobNapier Napier Does it improve the performance if I use CGImage, and then convert it to NSImage, sometimes if I load a file bigger than 1MB, it will take time to load it into memory (almost 4 seconds)

I wouldn't necessarily expect a performance improvement just from CGImage. You'd need to do some profiling to see what different approaches do. For example, loading with Data with mappedIfSafe could improve things. But this may be identical to NSImage(contentsOf:) for a local URL. Alternately, depending on when you can afford to take the performance hit, you could consider NSImage(byReferencing:) to load the image lazily. (But you need to use isValid later to ensure it's valid.) I wouldn't guess on this; I would measure in your app.

If there were a magic "it go faster" solution with no trade-offs, NSImage would just use that approach always.
